# LearnDash - limit number of answers for multiple choice questions

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am working with the LearnDash plugin for Wordpress, and was wondering if there is a way to limit the number of selections a user can make.

For example, if a user has been given 5 answers on a multiple choice question, and i want them to only be able to select 3 of those answers, and no more (however they may select less).
Something like greying out the boxes after they have selected 3 would probably be fine.

Are there any addons or something which I can use to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you think the variable or data is stored that you need to change?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS i have no idea. i just installed the plugin, and was looking for the outlined feature which seems to be missing.